# extract a common subset of two patch files

Tags: version-control, tree, diff, patch

I have three source trees, A, B, and C. A is the original tree. B and C are modifications of a A, created by 2 different developers.

I have taken diff's of A with B and A with C.

But there are many changes in the two diff files that are common. Meaning A is not the latest point of divergence for B and C. Instead A was modified to a point where it became D (that I don't have), and B and C were then modified over D.

My question is: what can I do with the two diff files (besides manual labor) to extract their maximum common subset? so that I apply that subset as a patch to A to get D

EDIT 1: Illustration:

```
A ---> D ---> B
        \---> C
```

EDIT 2: I have looked at patchutils tools but didn't find one that does what I need. I have also looked at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1079) but the method mentioned there doesn't give correct output.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how you would do this by hand, but you could take a look at 3-way merge concept: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(revision_control)#Three-way_merge

Some great revision control system uses 3-way merge for its merging algorithm (such as Mercurial). You can also look for standalone 3-way merge tools here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460198/best-free-3-way-merge-tool-for-windows

Comment: I am an avid git user and I might be able to use it for my task ... but I'm wondering if anyone ever encountered such a problem before git and mercurial were around

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys, I came up with the following solution (without using git, mercurial etc). (DISCLAIMER: may have typos, might require changes to work on your side)

The underlying method/algorithm is as follows:

1. Split both diff files into smaller components
2. Compare the components of one diff file with those of the other and select those that are identical in both
3. Join the selected components to create a new diff file with correct formatting

Each of my diff files has file-level diffs and each file-level diff has one or more hunks. If by components I mean file-level components then the extraction can be done with patchutils tools "splitdiff" and "combinediff" as follows:

```
$ # Step 1
$ mkdir AB_components; cp AB.diff AB_components; cd AB_components
$ splitdiff -ad AB.diff
$ cd ..
$ mkdir AC_components; cp AC.diff AC_components; cd AC_components
$ splitdiff -ad AC.diff
$ cd ..
$
$ # Step 2
$ mkdir AD_components;
$ for f in `diff -rs AB_components AC_components | grep 'are identical$' | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d'/' -f2`; do cp AB_components/$f AD_components; done
$
$ # Step 3
$ cd AD_components; touch AD.diff
$ for f in `ls ._*`; do combinediff AD.diff $f > tmpfile; mv tmpfile AD.diff; done
```

However if by components I mean individual hunks then splitdiff is not enough. I found a tool [here](https://gist.github.com/1351683) that splits a file into individual hunks (I had to make slight change in that script to make it work on my machine ... specifically I had to comment out the "require 'file.rb'" line).

For step 2 I had to run a double for-loop for finding 'identical' hunks:

```
$ for f in `ls AB_components.mod/*`; do for g in `ls AC_components.mod/*`; do diff -s $f $g | grep 'are identical$'; done; done > identical_hunks
$ for f in `cat identical_hunks | cut -d' ' -f2`; do cp AB_components/`basename $f` AD_components; done
```

For the combining I had to follow a two step process:

- Step 3 part 1: I first combined hunks belonging to same file(s) to create a diff for each file
- Step 3 part 2: I used combinediff to join those diff files to create one final diff file

For step 3 part 1, I created the following shell script (let's call it combinehunks.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
echo 'diff header line:'
firstpatchfile=`ls -1v $filename.*.patch | head -1`
head -2 $firstpatchfile
files=`ls -1v $filename.*.patch`
for f in $files; do tail -n +3 $f; done
```

and I used it as follows:

```
$ mkdir AD_filelevel_components; cd AD_filelevel_components
$ for f in `ls ../AD_components/* | rev | cut -d'.' -f3- | rev | sort | uniq`; do ../combinehunks.sh $f > `basename $f`.patch; done
```

Step 3 part 2 is same as step 3 in the file-level case, except using the AD_filelevel_components directory instead of AD_components.

Caveats/Notes:

1. I had to remove timestamps from `---` and `+++` header lines before proceeding with this work (timestamps are often different and would needlessly keep the diff components from being identical)
2. I also removed `Only in ...` lines from the diff file before the procedure.
3. For hunk-level work, I had to change @@ lines before comparison. Basically I removed the 2nd portion of the lines, i.e., changing `@@ -nnn,nn +mmm,mm @@` to `@@ -nnn,nn @@`. Note the use of AB_components.mod versus AB_components above.This is only for the comparison. Hunks that go into the final diff must have the correct @@ lines otherwise combinediff will report errors
4. By 'diff file' and 'patch file' I mean the same thing. Throughout this work I used unified diff format exclusively i.e., `diff -u`

AB_components.mod was created like this:

```
$ cp -r AB_components{,.mod}
$ cd AB_components.mod
$ for f in `ls`; do sed -i -e 's/@@ \(.*\) \(.*\) @@$/@@ \1 @@/g' $f; done
```

EDIT 1: I had to take the following additional step to fix the issue with buggy ruby code (mentioned in my comment below):

```
$ cd ..; cp -r AB_components{,.mod2}; cd AB_components.mod2
$ for f in `ls`; do echo $f:`tail -1 $f`; done | grep ':diff ' | cut -d':' -f1 > ../bad_files
$ for f in `cat ../bad_files`; do head -n -1 ../AB_components/$f > $f; done
```

Comment: just discovered: gist ruby code is buggy ... either that or my removing of the "require 'file.rb'" line made it produce incorrect results ... about 30% of the output files show a spurious 'diff' line at the end of the file ...

still working for a fix ...